# Как писать программу под WinXP и Win7

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-7

Добрый день.
Среда RAD Studio 2009 на Windows XP. Какие есть возможности писать программу под Win7? Какие есть возможности среды или приемы? Или только переносить RAD на Win7?

Исполняемый код должен работать под WinXP и Win7.

Comment: Спасибо за советы.
Попытаюсь конкретизировать.

Была написана программа под XP для замены сертификата в хранилище. Под XP все работает нормально. При запуске под Win7 выдается ошибка. Используется библиотека CAPICOM. 
И еще, встречал такой термин как удаленная отладка. Это к тому что компилировать под XP а запускать и отлаживать на виртуальной машине под Win7.

Comment: Интересный вопрос.  
У самого на одной программе, написанной на XP, под семеркой банально не хотел работать OpenDialog. Причем только в одном месте программы. И хоть тресни.  
Сейчас тоже заметил проблему, запустив новую софтину на семерке. Половина визуальных (стандартных) компонентов формы непрорисовываются, а видны просто прямоугольники черного цвета.  

Так что на выходных придется поработать дома, на 7рочке)

Answer (score 2):

Исполняемый код будет работать в любом случае. Сложности наступят, если вы захотите использовать особенности Windows, которые есть в семерке, но нет в XP (навроде новых MessageBox-ов с выбором и управляемым поведением кнопки приложения в Панели задач).

Если есть возможность, я  бы на вашем месте не заморачивался и для подобных вещей воспользовался готовыми обертками. У TMS и DevExpress были подобные вещи в наборах компонентов.

Answer (score 0):

Интересный, гибкий вопрос. Тут однозначно ответить на него нельзя.

К чему это я.

> Какие есть возможности писать
> программу под Win7?

Любые, Вы, например, можете писать хоть на 98 (наверное перегнул, но суть та же), а потом в режиме совместимости запускать на 7ке.

> Какие есть возможности среды или приемы?

Возможности среды таковы, что она может из исходных кодов, используя компилятор, создавать определённую бинарную последовательность, такую, что ОС сможет воспроизвести механизм описанный в кодах. И не важно на какой системе вы будете писать - эта последовательность будет идентична на 1-3(может больше) поколениях ОС и получать идентичный результат. Если говорить о приёмах - использовать независимый от файловой системы код. Например, программа + реестр = отличная динамика и никаких файловых ошибок.

> Или только переносить RAD на Win7?

Это уже Ваш выбор. Вы можете установить эту же версию снова. Ну или выше.

Comment: Реестр со слов самих разработчиков Windows уже пару версий как не комильфо. Локальные настройки и подобные мелочи давно рекомендуют хранить в `%APPDATA%`.

Answer (score 0):

есть по сути два семейства Windows: NT и остальные (в том числе 95,98).
У них есть, и значительные, различия, хотя часто API и идентичны (просто не работают).
2000 - XP - Vista - 7 это всё одна платформа NT (хотя и значительно доработана, особенно начиная с Vista).
Вы не заметите разницы собирая программу в Windows XP и запуская её в Windows 7.
Исключение может быть, если вы специально захотите использовать возможности Windows 7, но, или в Windows XP это никак не проявится (могут просто пропасть какие то графические эффекты/"красивости"), или программа (сложный случай) просто не запустится.
Потому, надо четко это понимать, стоит ли ограничивать её применимость определенной ОС?
Чисто внешне, различия/возможности как правило в GUI - графическом интерфейсе пользователя.

Не переживайте и спокойно программируйте.

Если вы сталкиваетесь с ошибкой - конкретизируйте её (на что именно ругается и т.д.), как правило это частные случаи, хотя и могут относиться к версии ОС в целом. Например - ошибка с путями (часть путей изменены в 7), с правами доступа (например - по умолчанию, в Windows 7 закрыта директория "Program Files" и т.д.)